# Algorithm for building a pre-shared dictionary for compression

Tags: dictionary, compression

Some compression algorithms support a pre-shared dictionary, but I can't find any information on actually how to construct the dictionary.

This can be stated more formally like so:

Given N input byte sequences of various lengths, find a byte sequence of length D that minimises the total compressed size of the N inputs, given that any sequence in the inputs that matches part of the dictionary can be replaced be replaced by a reference to the dictionary. Each reference occupies R bytes (e.g. roughly 3 for LZ4).

It's probably too slow to find the optimal dictionary, but how do you find a good one in a reasonable time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zstd --train`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zstd) to build a good dictionary from a large set of small files. (Look for the "DICTIONARY BUILDER" section of the man page.) The same dictionary would be good for other LZ compressors as well.

For the algorithm, the source code [cites](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/ammoffat/abstracts/lpmw16www.pdf):

```
Constructs a dictionary using a heuristic based on the following paper:
 *
 * Liao, Petri, Moffat, Wirth
 * Effective Construction of Relative Lempel-Ziv Dictionaries
 * Published in WWW 2016.
```

Comment: I'm looking for the *algorithm* though. Is there a description of it somewhere so I don't need to read the source code?

Comment: @Timmmm See updated answer.